# How to use frame size in minus for UIView iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiview, size, frame

I have one critical doubt. I have set a frame size in minus for UIView. Example  (-250,0,300,400) in Landscape mode iPhone. Now, my doubt is if i submit this app to App Store with this value they will reject this app or accept. Please clarify my doubt. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that so you can submit your application for review.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Mihai Fratu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with setting the origin of a view's frame to off the screen (i.e. less than (0,0)) - this is commonly used when preparing a view that slides onto the screen, for example. In your case only the rightmost 50 points of the view will be visible.

It certainly won't be a reason to reject the app from the app store.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.jrturton.